# Django 3.2 Migrations - "NoneType" object has no attribute "_meta"

Tags: python, django

$ docker-compose exec myapp python manage.py migrate

I've got this error after modifying my model, how can I rollback or fix the issue ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/src/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 268, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 42, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    models.signals.post_migrate.send(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adminactions/models.py", line 9, in create_extra_permissions_handler
    p.create_extra_permissions()
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adminactions/perms.py", line 34, in create_extra_permissions
    content_types = ContentType.objects.get_for_models(*models)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 89, in get_for_models
    opts_models = needed_opts.pop(ct.model_class()._meta, [])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Can you post the model that you just modified?

Comment: Thanks @Lemayzeur , please find the model below. I just wanted to rename the column application_domain by application_domain_name

Comment: @KémoTouréJr.: please [edit] the question. Do *not* post it as an answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am new to Stackoverflow, the editor is not accepting my edits

Comment: @KémoTouréJr.: you need to add enough text. Code-only questions (or questions with a lot of code compared to text) are not accepted.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem well noted, thanks